# Azure Functiona app - Powershell - Throwing error but the function works - Az/AZTable

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I'm working on a powershell function on Azure.
The code works without any issue on my machine, but when I try to use the same on Azure I get this long error below:

```
2021-05-04T14:56:44.027 [Error] ERROR: Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.Exception :Type : System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingExceptionMessage : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.ParameterName : NameErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameterLine : 3Offset : 1CommandInvocation :MyCommand : Import-ModuleScriptLineNumber : 3OffsetInLine : 1HistoryId : 1ScriptName : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1Line : Import-ModulePositionMessage : At D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1:3 char:1+ Import-Module+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~PSScriptRoot : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1PSCommandPath : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1InvocationName : Import-ModulePipelineLength : 1PipelinePosition : 1CommandOrigin : InternalErrorRecord :Exception :Type : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordExceptionMessage : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.HResult : -2146233087CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Module], ParentContainsErrorRecordExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommandInvocationInfo :MyCommand : Import-ModuleScriptLineNumber : 3OffsetInLine : 1HistoryId : 1ScriptName : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1Line : Import-ModulePositionMessage : At D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1:3 char:1+ Import-Module+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~PSScriptRoot : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1PSCommandPath : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1CommandOrigin : InternalScriptStackTrace : at <ScriptBlock>, D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1: line 3TargetSite :Name : PromptForMissingMandatoryParametersDeclaringType : System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35MemberType : MethodModule : System.Management.Automation.dllStackTrace :at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.PromptForMissingMandatoryParameters(Collection`1 fieldDescriptionList, Collection`1 missingMandatoryParameters)at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.HandleUnboundMandatoryParameters(Int32 validParameterSetCount, Boolean processMissingMandatory, Boolean promptForMandatory, Boolean isPipelineInputExpected, Collection`1& missingMandatoryParameters)at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParameters(Collection`1 arguments)at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.BindCommandLineParameters()at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.Prepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoPrepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Start(Boolean incomingStream)at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternalSource : System.Management.AutomationHResult : -2146233087CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Module], ParameterBindingExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommandInvocationInfo :MyCommand : Import-ModuleScriptLineNumber : 3OffsetInLine : 1HistoryId : 1ScriptName : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1Line : Import-ModulePositionMessage : At D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1:3 char:1+ Import-Module+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~PSScriptRoot : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1PSCommandPath : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1CommandOrigin : InternalScriptStackTrace : at <ScriptBlock>, D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1: line 3Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException : Result: ERROR: Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.Exception :Type : System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingExceptionMessage : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.ParameterName : NameErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameterLine : 3Offset : 1CommandInvocation :MyCommand : Import-ModuleScriptLineNumber : 3OffsetInLine : 1HistoryId : 1ScriptName : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1Line : Import-ModulePositionMessage : At D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1:3 char:1+ Import-Module+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~PSScriptRoot : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1PSCommandPath : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1InvocationName : Import-ModulePipelineLength : 1PipelinePosition : 1CommandOrigin : InternalErrorRecord :Exception :Type : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordExceptionMessage : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.HResult : -2146233087CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Module], ParentContainsErrorRecordExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommandInvocationInfo :MyCommand : Import-ModuleScriptLineNumber : 3OffsetInLine : 1HistoryId : 1ScriptName : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1Line : Import-ModulePositionMessage : At D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1:3 char:1+ Import-Module+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~PSScriptRoot : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1PSCommandPath : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1CommandOrigin : InternalScriptStackTrace : at <ScriptBlock>, D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1: line 3TargetSite :Name : PromptForMissingMandatoryParametersDeclaringType : System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35MemberType : MethodModule : System.Management.Automation.dllStackTrace :at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.PromptForMissingMandatoryParameters(Collection`1 fieldDescriptionList, Collection`1 missingMandatoryParameters)at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.HandleUnboundMandatoryParameters(Int32 validParameterSetCount, Boolean processMissingMandatory, Boolean promptForMandatory, Boolean isPipelineInputExpected, Collection`1& missingMandatoryParameters)at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParameters(Collection`1 arguments)at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.BindCommandLineParameters()at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.Prepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoPrepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Start(Boolean incomingStream)at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternalSource : System.Management.AutomationHResult : -2146233087CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Module], ParameterBindingExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommandInvocationInfo :MyCommand : Import-ModuleScriptLineNumber : 3OffsetInLine : 1HistoryId : 1ScriptName : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1Line : Import-ModulePositionMessage : At D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1:3 char:1+ Import-Module+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~PSScriptRoot : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1PSCommandPath : D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1CommandOrigin : InternalScriptStackTrace : at <ScriptBlock>, D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1: line 3Exception: Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.Stack: at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.PromptForMissingMandatoryParameters(Collection`1 fieldDescriptionList, Collection`1 missingMandatoryParameters)at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.HandleUnboundMandatoryParameters(Int32 validParameterSetCount, Boolean processMissingMandatory, Boolean promptForMandatory, Boolean isPipelineInputExpected, Collection`1& missingMandatoryParameters)at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParameters(Collection`1 arguments)at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.BindCommandLineParameters()at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.Prepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoPrepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Start(Boolean incomingStream)at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)



2021-05-04T14:57:06.367 [Warning] WARNING: INITIALIZATION: Fallback context save mode to process because of error during checking token cache persistence: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\.IdentityService'..
```

The function installs automatically the Module needed (Az and AzTable) and it actually work after the second message.

Any help?

Comment: From the stack trace in the first line, it looks like you've got a call to ```Import-Module``` with no ```-Name``` parameter - ```Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.``` and ```PositionMessage :  At D:\home\site\wwwroot\MYAPP1\run.ps1:3 char:1 + Import-Module```.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know how I missed the import!
I'm now left with 

2021-05-05T08:20:51.659 [Warning] WARNING: INITIALIZATION: Fallback context save mode to process because of error during checking token cache persistence: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\.IdentityService'..~

But I think is AzAccounts now that has issue